# Crear lista a partir de una frase

Tags: python

Tengo lo siguiente

```
frase= 'Hola mundo, esta,, es una frase {{de:ejemplo}'
```

Código de ejemplo

```
lista=[] 
lista.append(frase)
```

¿Cómo puedo crear una lista en la que cada palabra sea un elemento? Gracias!

Ya he probado:

```
separador= ' '
lista= frase.split(separador) pero:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Y creo que es porque la frase en sí ya la he convertido en lista, ahora necesito separar los elementos. Y lo he comprobado porque:

```
frase[0]
Hola mundo, esta,, es una frase {{de:ejemplo}
frase[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Una solución que se me ha ocurrido es directamente seleccionar el elemento que quiero, por ejemplo, pedir que me diga las palabras que hay después de ':' (en este caso 'ejemplo'). Pero no sé bien cómo hacer eso.

He conseguido la forma de hacerlo, o eso creo, pero ahora necesito que imprima lo que hay después de 'de:' es decir, que imprima 'ejemplo'

```
for w in frase:
 if w == 'ejemplo'
  print(w)
```

Pero no imprime nada.

Comment: Podrías añadir el código que has intentado? La posible solución es usar el método [slit](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: lista=[]
  lista.append(frase)

Comment: Deberías de añadir el error a la pregunta. Esta zona es para comentarios.

Comment: si consideramos una palabra como "los caracteres entre dos espacios", el método split aplicado a la frase debería de devolver una lista con cada palabra. Si no es eso, tendrás que hacer algo más complejo (como por ejemplo, usar regex).

Comment: La verdad, la respuesta dependerá de que consideres como "palabra".

Comment: Lo que necesito es saber cómo separar los elementos de la lista que ahora aparecen como un único elemento.

Comment: Se trata de una sola frase o una lista de frases?

Comment: Cambiarle tipo a una variable a mitad de camino es garantía de problemas más adelante. Por ejemplo, ¿`frase` es una cadena o una lista?

Comment: Si tratas de armar una lista de listas de palabras, tendrás que obtener la frase, separarla con split y recién ahí agregarla a la lista.

Comment: El problema es que la frase se obtiene directamente mediante web scraping (simulado), es decir, que yo obtengo "frase" pero no puedo modificar su tipología o naturaleza. ¿Es imposible separar los elementos si ya es un único elemento de una lista? Frase es una lista entonces.

Comment: Por un lado, si querés modificar el contenido de una lista, entonces tenés que recorrer la lista con un for, modificar el elemento y agregarlo a una nueva lista. Por otro, si sale de web scrapping, split no va a separar las palabras como buscas. Lo que buscas es obtener lo que viene después de los ":"?

Comment: Estaría bueno que nos indiques lo que quieres obtener y una demostración (sea pasando algunos de los links visitados como un código que hayas diseñado) de tu esfuerzo para que no paresca que querés que lo hagan por vos.

Comment: Bueno, sería una solución parcial Dante S. pero si pudiera al menos decirle que devolviera lo que está después de 'de:' para que devolviera 'ejemplo' al menos arreglaría el problema en parte. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso con la función for?

Comment: No es una función, es un tipo de bucle. Buscá tutoriales en internet, hay muchos que lo explican con mas tiempo y detalle.

Comment: Dante S. he visitado esto principalmente: https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/python/python-split-list-into-chunks/#dividir-la-lista-en-python-en-fragmentos-usando-el-m%25C3%25A9todo-itertools

Comment: Ese link te indica como separar en partes iguales una secuencia. Eso no te va a servir para hacer lo que buscas. Si querés que pueda darte una respuesta, te recomiendo tener en cuenta lo que dije sobre conocer bien tu objetivo.

Comment: De acuerdo, he probado la el bucle for. Lo voy a añadir a la pregunta principal, de momento quiero que imprima lo que hay tras los dos puntos, con eso creo que ya podré separar luego la frase.

Comment: Tengo la sospecha, pero pregunto ante la duda: Desde los dos puntos hasta donde? Hasta el cierre de llaves? Hasta el final de la cadena?

Comment: Sólo la palabra ejemplo, es decir, justo el elemento posterior.

Comment: Y cual sería el final del "elemento posterior"? Por cierto, que sucede si aparece "{de:" mas de una vez?

Comment: Sería 'ejemplo' eliminando el '}' del final. Sólo aparece una vez, pero si apareciera más de una, estaría bien que pusiera ambos elementos. Si la frase fuera: 
"de: ejemplo} de: 22" preferiría que imprimiera 'ejemplo, 22'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Una solución sin usar regex

```
def findall(cadena, subcadena):
    """
    Esta función devuelve todas las posiciones donde
    subcadena aparece en cadena
    """

    # esta es la posición desde donde buscar
    # inicia en 0 (primer caracter)
    # y va cambiando a la ultima ocurrencia + el largo de subcadena
    pos = 0
    posiciones = []

    # Iniciamos un bucle "infinito"
    # No te preocupes, usamos break más adelante para detenerlo.
    while True:
        # buscamos desde pos a subcadena
        nuevapos = cadena.find(subcadena, pos)

        # si nuevapos es -1, es decir, no se encontró nada
        # rompemos el bucle
        if(nuevapos == -1):
            break

        posiciones.append(nuevapos)
        
        pos = nuevapos + len(subcadena)

    return posiciones

frases = ["hola {de:mundo} {{de:l}mar}",
          "color {de:tierra} y {node:agua}"]

palabras = []
de = "{de:"

for frase in frases:
    for pos in findall(frase, de):
        pos += len(de)

        # tomamos todo lo que sigue de la cadena desde
        # la ocurrencia de de hasta el final.
        palabra = frase[pos:]
        # asumimos que hay una llave y buscamos donde está
        # cortamos la cadena donde aparece su primer cierre de llaves
        palabra = palabra[:palabra.find("}")]

        palabras.append(palabra)

print(frases)
print(palabras)
```

Produce:

```
['hola {de:mundo} {{de:l}mar}', 'color {de:tierra} y {node:agua}']
['mundo', 'l', 'tierra']
```

#### Una solución usando regex

A veces, las expresiones regulares pueden ser muy utiles y hasta más simples. Pero son un poco mas lentas e implican aprender un "minilenguaje". Python permite su uso a través del modulo [re](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html)

```
import re

frases = ["hola {de:mundo} {{de:l}mar}",
          "color {de:tierra} y {node:agua}"]

pattern = re.compile("\{de:([^}]*)")

palabras = []

for frase in frases:
    for match in pattern.finditer(frase):
        palabras.append(match[1])

print(frases)
print(palabras)
```

Que produce lo mismo.

**Explicación de la regex**

*`\{de` coincide con la cadena `{de`. La barra invertida actúa como caracter de escape y le indica a la regex "esto no tiene ningún significado especial, es el caracter {"

- los parentesis indican que queremos agrupar esa parte de la regex.
- `[^}]` cualquier caracter que no sea }. No es necesario escapar } ya que el modulo re ya se da cuenta, por estar entre corchetes, que estamos trabajando con dicho caracter. El ^ significa "que no sea".
- `*` significa "0 o mas ocurrecias del grupo o regex anterior".

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: De nada María c: